# Driving three LEDs in series with different Vf at 700mA

Tags: led, voltage-divider

Given LED1: Vf = 3VDC for 700mA ---- and ---- LED2: Vf = 4VDC for 700mA

If I put LED1 + LED1 + LED2 (in series) and apply 10VDC across them, will I have 700mA flowing through them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be more precise to say that with a LED1+LED1+LED2 stack @ 700 mA that you would have approximately 10V Vf.

The Voltage vs. Current curves for diodes are very abrupt (exponential)  it is never a good idea to drive them as if they are voltage mode devices.

If you apply 10V across that stack it is unlikely that you will have 700 mA exactly flowing through it.  So you'd have very poor brightness control as a minimum and you could potentially have it run away from you, depending on the LED's response to temperature and various other factors. etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

Vf1 = 3 V, Vf2 = 4V.

Vf1 + Vf1 + Vf2 = 10V.

HOWEVER!!!!

LEDs, like almost all generic diodes, provide essentially NO current-limiting.  You put voltage across them, they will generally draw as much current as the supply is willing to put out, until the inevitable occurs.

You MUST use some mechanism to limit the current through the LED.  The simplest mechanism is more voltage and a current-limiting resistor.

In this particular case, 12V, 3.3 ohms, and your LED string would give you 600 mA, instead of your desired 700 mA.  (You'd also be dissipating just over 1.2 Watts in the resistor, which isn't that bad compared to 7 Watts in the LED string.)

Incidentally, that's about 70 times as much current as I'm used to seeing in LEDs.  The numbers I'm used to seeing are Vf = 1.7V, I = 10 mA, Vcc = 5V, and R = 330 ohms.  (Yes, I'm giving away my age here.)

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes, but device to device variations and temperature dependances (including self-heating) will make you have a wild range of values, although centered around 700 mA.